# Pass array in params and create row in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I iterate over an array in params and create row in database for each item? I am trying to achieve it with code below:

```
  def create
    @attachment = @project.attachments.new(params[:attachment][:file])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @attachment.save
        format.json { render json: {files: [@attachment]}, status: :created, location: [@project, @attachment] }
      else
        format.json { render json: @attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But each time I get this error:

````
NoMethodError at /projects/10/attachments
=========================================

&gt; undefined method `stringify_keys' for #&lt;ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005867d38&gt;

app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb, line 46
--------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
   41     end
   42   
   43     # POST /attachments
   44     # POST /attachments.json
   45     def create
&gt;  46       @attachment = @project.attachments.new(params[:attachment][:file])
   47   
   48       respond_to do |format|
   49         if @attachment.save
   50           format.json { render json: {files: [@attachment]}, status: :created, location: [@project, @attachment] }
   51         else
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:46:in `create'
 - script/rails:6:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
 - script/rails:0:in `&lt;main&gt;'
````

And that is how my params look like:
[image: params]

And finally my model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file, :project_id, :issue_id, :attachment
  resourcify
  mount_uploader :file, AttachmentsUploader
end
```

How can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`new` method takes a hash:

```
@project.attachments.new(file: params[:attachment][:file])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sadly now I get error as follows: `&gt; can't convert nil into String` Should I try to convert whole array to hash and then take a try? What do you think about this approach?

Comment: I think that you're failing to upload the file properly. See https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave for examples.